# Word|VBA - Range.Goto - How to make it work properly?

Tags: vba, range, ms-word

My test scenario:
I'm in Outline view.
I have loaded a range from a bookmark into a variable.
I want to do the following actually:

```
dim StartRange as range, nowLevel as integer, startLevel as integer
set StartRange  = Selection.range
nowLevel = StartRange.Paragraphs(1).OutlineLevel
Do    
    StartRange.GoTo What:=wdGoToHeading, Which:=wdGoToPrevious, Count:=1
    nowLevel = StartRange.Paragraphs(1).OutlineLevel
    If nowLevel < startlevel Then ActiveWindow.View.ExpandOutline
Loop Until nowLevel = 1
```

I have manually debugged the code and used Startrange.select to check where the range object stands.
It turned out that it does not move at all.
I have tested then separately, and my impression is that Range.goto does not work at all as it never moves itself anywhere. (While doing the same things with Selection.goto does move...)
What am I missing out on?
**Edit:**
I have added more details to my code snippet above; this should be enogh to run a test for anybody, however the problem is GENERAL for me for any random ranges in usecases (when being on Outline view, either AllLevelsVisible or Collapsed): "`StartRange.GoTo What:=wdGoHeading, Which:=wdGoToPrevious, Count:=1`"

I have actually solved my original problem now, using selection instead of range, but it would still be great to know for later, what is the problem with range.goto
My other thread with the workaround: [Word | VBA - How to start Word in Outline view - opened exactly where you left off?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50160521/word-vba-how-to-start-word-in-outline-view-opened-exactly-where-you-left-o/50160522#50160522)

Comment: Hard to say - you don't provide a reproducible scenario. Best if you provide a full `Sub`, including what startLevel is. And also describe the minimal Word document content and what you want to do with it - it's not clear what the code should be accomplishing, exactly.

Comment: Hi Cindy, I have added more info upon your request, and ready to provide even more if you need it - i was just busy creating a workaround, because i needed some soultion -but I'm still interested in finding out what is the problem with the range.goto (please remove your -1 and cooperate further with me on this)

Comment: Question from my comment in the other post: Which version of Word are you using?

Comment: Using 2016 Professional Plus , Version 1804, Build 9226.2114

Comment: Does it work on Your Version for example? - Can you provide me any type of code snippet, where range.goto is working for you properly, so that i can cross-validate

Comment: + Please remove your -1 ! I'm fully present and cooperating.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code you use `StartRange.GoTo`, but your next line uses `StartRange` again, which just takes the original value.

Perhaps:

```
Set newRange = StartRange.GoTo(What:=wdGoHeading, Which:=wdGoToPrevious, Count:=1)
nowLevel = newRange.Paragraphs(1).OutlineLevel
```

Depending on what you want to do, the following may be more applicable:

```
Set StartRange = StartRange.GoTo(What:=wdGoHeading, Which:=wdGoToPrevious, Count:=1)
nowLevel = StartRange.Paragraphs(1).OutlineLevel
```

*Edit: Additional information based on a question in the comments.*

Some range methods (such as `MoveStart` and `Expand`) work to actively modify the range parameters. The `GoTo` method is a function that returns a `Range` object rather than activity modifying the referenced object. However, MSDN documentation is not clear about this latter part and implies that using the `GoTo` method moves the range. `GoTo` does move the insertion point, but this is not the same as moving a `Range`.

Soapbox: I am not happy with the new MSDN content - it is now bland and provides only basic descriptions. The older in-depth information (including limitations, edge cases and potential error factors) is being edited out - probably seen as an *improvement* by some.

Comment: You are right! That makes me both happy and confused. I used my original syntax consequently derived from: "StartRange.MoveStart Unit:=wdWord, Count:=1" and "StartRange.Expand Unit:=wdWord". In Both of these cases StartRange is modified properly without the need of using "set StartRange =" before the expression. Also from the ms page this difference is not really obvious: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/word-vba/articles/range-goto-method-word . I will give you the green tick soon, but can you please comment on this difference of sytax also?