# Word | VBA - How to start Word in Outline view - opened exactly where you left off?

Tags: vba, ms-word, bookmarks, outline-view

In MsWord, even though the last location of the cursor is saved automatically, that you could recall by Shift+F5 upon re-opening a document,
- You can neither set it to start in Outline view. 
- Nor use that or any other bookmark on a collapsed Outline view to jump on.
Bookmark locations for a collapsed outline are invisible.
The closest option one can achieve is to open all levels of the outline and Then jump on the bookmark. 
For the several hundred page scientific documents we use daily that is not acceptable, becuse it heavily decreases the usability of the Outline editor. 
Web-view has nowdays also a collapsable Heading-system (where ironically also the bookmark goto works properly), but that lacks other important features that the real Outline view has.
It seems as if two sub-project teams had a hard time collaborating in the Office development team.
I haven't found a working solution on the net for days, so finally I sat down to come up with a reliably working solution (after trashing 3 dead-end ideas).
I will post the VBA code snippets in the response.

Comment: One reason you didn't get any useful response is because the question (I saw the one) didn't contain all the information about what you needed (I see you just updated that - this instant)... Which version of Word are you working with? If 2013 or 2016 there is a possible solution in the normal Page View - because these vesions support collapsing and expanding headings.

Comment: I'm using 2016, but I think it affects at least the past 3-4 versions down to 2003 where it was more or less OK. Cindy - if you read carefully, I have already mentioned in my post your suggestion about normal view's collapsible headings - that feature is the same as in Web view. Unfortunately that lacks other important features of the real Outline view so they are not interchangeable to use. Anyway: the workaround is Stable! its only a shame that it did not function out of the box. Please help me on the other thread finding the issue with range.goto

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For my solution I had to create a separate bookmark for each heading level above cursor location, to be able to open them one by one when the document is re-opened.
Note: I had some issues using range.goto, so instead I had to stick with manipulating Selection for now.
There are two sections - one is for saving the location and closing the document, the other is for opening it properly. - Best to place them inside Normal.dot modules.
**the DocumentClosing macro:**

```
Sub SaveAndClose()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        Call IttTartok
        ActiveDocument.Close savechanges:=True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
Private Sub IttTartok()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim Level As Variant
    Dim InduloSel As Range, KereSel As Range
    Dim myLevel As Long

'Delete all aiding bookmarks from the last save cycle.
    If ActiveDocument.Bookmarks.Exists("IttL1") = True Then ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("IttL1").Delete
    If ActiveDocument.Bookmarks.Exists("IttL2") = True Then ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("IttL2").Delete
    If ActiveDocument.Bookmarks.Exists("IttL3") = True Then ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("IttL3").Delete
    If ActiveDocument.Bookmarks.Exists("IttL4") = True Then ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("IttL4").Delete
    If ActiveDocument.Bookmarks.Exists("IttL5") = True Then ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("IttL5").Delete
    If ActiveDocument.Bookmarks.Exists("IttL6") = True Then ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("IttL6").Delete
    If ActiveDocument.Bookmarks.Exists("IttL7") = True Then ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("IttL7").Delete
    If ActiveDocument.Bookmarks.Exists("IttL8") = True Then ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("IttL8").Delete
    If ActiveDocument.Bookmarks.Exists("IttL9") = True Then ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("IttL9").Delete
    If ActiveDocument.Bookmarks.Exists("IttLAll") = True Then ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("IttLAll").Delete
'Save the cursor location in a Bookmark and check if it is a heading or Bodytext
    ActiveDocument.Bookmarks.Add Range:=selection.Range, Name:="IttLAll"
    myLevel = selection.Paragraphs(1).OutlineLevel
    If myLevel = 10 Then
        selection.GoTo wdGoToHeading, wdGoToPrevious, 1
        myLevel = selection.Paragraphs(1).OutlineLevel
        ActiveDocument.Bookmarks.Add Range:=selection.Range, Name:="IttL" & myLevel
    End If
'Search for the upline headings of the original cursor location
        For Level = myLevel - 1 To 1 Step -1
                selection.Find.ClearFormatting
                selection.Find.Style = ActiveDocument.Styles(((-(Level + 1))))
                With selection.Find
                    .Text = ""
                    .Replacement.Text = ""
                    .Forward = False
                    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
                    .Format = True
                    .MatchCase = False
                    .MatchWholeWord = False
                    .MatchWildcards = False
                    .MatchSoundsLike = False
                    .MatchAllWordForms = False

                    .Execute
                End With
'...and save the location of every upline heading in a separate Bookmark
                If selection.Find.Found Then
                     ActiveDocument.Bookmarks.Add Range:=selection.Range, Name:="IttL" & Level
                End If
        Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

**...and the Opener macro:**
(note: keep the name, that is needed for auto exacution upon starting of new doc.)

```
Sub AutoOpen()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        ActiveWindow.View = wdOutlineView
        ActiveWindow.View.ShowHeading 1
        Call WhereILeftOff
    End If
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Private Sub WhereILeftOff()
Dim i As Variant
If ActiveDocument.Bookmarks.Exists("IttLAll") = True Then
    For i = 1 To 9
        If ActiveDocument.Bookmarks.Exists("IttL" & i) = True Then
            ActiveWindow.View.ExpandOutline ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("IttL" & i).Range
        Else
            selection.GoTo wdGoToBookmark, , , "IttLAll"
            selection.EndKey Unit:=wdLine, Extend:=wdMove
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
End If
End Sub
```